# Module not found : Can't resolve 'fs' in Electron/Nextjs

Tags: next.js, electron

I'm trying to check if a file exist and if not, starts to download in my eletron app.

The error i have is the next one :

```
error - ./node_modules/electron/index.js:1:0
Module not found:can't resolve 'fs'
null
```

Where i use the function

```js
 mainWindow.webContents.session.on(
    'will-download',
.....

   ipcMain.on('folder', (event, arg) => {
          if (arg === 'check') {
            const folder =
              app.getPath('userData') +
              '\\Local Storage\\' +
              privateHash.split('.')[0];
            var file = searchFile(folder);
            if (file != null) {
              OpenApp(
                folder + '\\' + file,
                meeting,
                token,
                company,
                avatar,
                scene
              );
            } else {
               sending a message to the renderer to download the file
              }
```

The searchFile function is something like this :

```js
const searchFile = (folder) => {
  var fs = require('fs');
  var files = fs.readdirSync(folder.split('.')[0]);
   ....
```

I have looked in stackOverflow to similar problems and try their solutions, but for me it doesn't work.If somebody can help it will be great.
I put nodeIntegration, in package.json browser..fs:false,path:false,os:false..,i add to next.config.js webpack config , nothing is working for me

Comment: please highligh code.

Comment: I'm not sure, if this is related to your issue. Make sure the code runs only server side!

Answer (score 0):

you are probably trying to run server side code on the browser, that is very common, i would suggest that you follow the calls stack and figure out where that code is being run a browser environment and and conditionally skip, EX

```js
if (typeof window === 'undefined') {
  // do server side stuff ex. you can run your function here.
} else {
 // if you are in a client environment do nothing and return
 return;
}
```

Comment: Exactly or importing a function from a file that imports server packages.